# Finding all square-free n such that $n\mid \sigma(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let $n$ be a positive squarefree integer, and $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of the all the factors of n, then find all the numbers $n$ satisfying:
$$ n\mid \sigma(n)$$
First of all, it seems like the only solutions is $n=6$,I tried to use p-adic valuation and prove n can't have primes $p \ge 5$, but it didn't work out pretty well, here is my work: 
Note that $n \le \sigma(n)$, note that $\sigma(n)$ is always even, hence $n$ is even. Let:
$$n=2^{2\alpha_1+1} \cdot p_2^{2\alpha_2+1} \cdot ... \cdot p_k^{2\alpha_k+1}$$
$$ \sigma(n)= (1+2^1+...+2^{2\alpha_1+1})(1+p_1^1+...+p_1^{2\alpha_2+1})...(1+p_k^1+...+p_ k^{2\alpha_k+1})=$$
$$(2^{2\alpha+2}-1)(\frac{p_1^{2\alpha_2+2}-1}{p_1-1})...(\frac{p_k^{2\alpha_k+2}-1}{p_k-1})=$$
$$(4^{\alpha+1}-1)(\frac{p_1^{2\alpha_2+2}-1}{p_1-1})...(\frac{p_k^{2\alpha_k+2}-1}{p_k-1})$$ 
Now we will prove that $n$ can't have primes $p_i \ge 5$  and $\alpha_1=0$
Assume n has primes $p_i \ge 5$, then $p_i^{2i+1} | n$ which implies:
$$p_i^{2i+1}| (4^{\alpha+1}-1)(\frac{p_1^{2\alpha_2+2}-1}{p_1-1})...(\frac{p_k^{2\alpha_k+2}-1}{p_k-1})$$ 
Note thet $v_{p_i} (p_i^{2i+1})=2i+1$, then:
$$ v_{p_i}((4^{\alpha+1}-1)(\frac{p_1^{2\alpha_2+2}-1}{p_1-1})...(\frac{p_k^{2\alpha_k+2}-1}{p_k-1})) \ge 2i+1$$
$$v_{p_i}((4^{\alpha+1}-1)+v_{p_i}(p_1^{2\alpha_2+2}-1)+...+v_{p_i}(p_k^{2\alpha_2+2}-1) -v_{p_i}(p_1-1)-...-v_{p_i}(p_k-1) \ge 2i+1$$...
At this point, I get stuck, and this approach didn't work, I don't have any other ideas other than looking to the number of the primes, could I get a hint please? ( I want to work this question by myself)

Comment: Your condition in $n$ is square-free, $n=\prod p_i^{2a_i+1}$ is some other condition. Square-free would be all $a_i=0.$

Comment: Basically, you've made it much harder on yourself. Square-free is a number with no repeated prime factors, so $n=\prod p_i$ distinct primes and $\sigma(n)=\prod (p_i+1).$ Then consider the largest prime factor $p$ of $n.$ It must be a divisor of some $p_j+1.$ But if $p_j<p$ then $p_j+1<p$ unless $p_j=2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Oh yes , I forgot this quite simple argument.

Comment: Well, OP forgot the definition of square-free, so you weren't going to get this simple argument if you used OPs definition. @Peter

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In the title , I read squarefree, so I thought only about squarefree numbers.

Comment: @Peter Ah, I read your reference to $k$-perfect as referring to OPs $k,$ but maybe it is $k=\sigma(n)/n?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh yes, my "k" has a completely other meaning. In fact it is the ratio you mentioned.

Comment: Numbers with the property $n\mid \sigma(n)$ are called "$k$-perfect" , where $k=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$

Comment: Oh now I understand, I can't believe I even did that mistake, thanks!